# PsychoPy: "Conditional" but random selection from list across two dimensions

Tags: psychopy

In my experiment, I am presenting images (faces) that are different across 2 dimensions: **face identity and emotion**.

There are 5 faces displaying 5 different emotional expressions; making 25 unique stimuli in total. These only need to be presented once (so 25 trials).

After I present one of the faces, the next face has to be different on only the emotion OR the identity, but the same on the other.

**Example:**

```
Face 1, emotion 1 -> face 3, emotion 1 -> face 3, emotion 4 -> ... etc.
```

1: is psychopy up to this task? I have mostly worked with the builder so far, except for some data-logging code, but I'd be happy to get more experienced with the coder.

My hunch is that I would need to add two columns to the list of trials, one for identity and one for emotion. Then use the getEarlierTrial call somehow, but I pretty much get lost at this point.

2: Would anyone be willing to point me in the right direction please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, anything should be possible in the coder because you have a full-fledged programming language available then. I think you would still have to provide more details on what you would like to achieve. Do all the pictures have to be used? What other constraints do you have on how the sequence is structured? Often it is easiest to define your desired sequence in a list at the start (using your constraints); then, you can just step through it during the experiment.

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex. 
All pictures will have to be used. There are 25 of them; 5 faces with 5 different emotional expressions. There are no other constraints that I could think of; it needs to be random BUT one of the dimensions of the one i am presenting needs to be the same as the previous trial. 
I might want to prevent three or more repetitions of the same face/emotion later, but that's not for now.
I don't have much experience with the Python language, but I could always use Matlab to reorder my list with these constraints for every participant.

Comment: The information on how many faces, how many emotions, how many total trials, and randomisation is key information that needs to be in the question rather than buried in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult to implement in Builder's normal mode of operation, which is to drive trials from a fixed list of conditions. Although the order of rows can be randomised across subjects, the pairings of values across columns remains constant.

The standard answer to this is what you allude to in your comment above: in code, shuffle the conditions file at the beginning of each experiment, so each subject is in essence having their trials driven by a unique conditions file.

You seem happy to do this in Matlab. That would work fine, as this stuff can be done before PsychoPy even launches. But it could also very easily be implemented in Python code. That way you could do everything in PsychoPy, and in this case there would be no need to abandon Builder. You'd just insert a code component with some code to run at the beginning of the experiment that customises a conditions file.

You'll need to create three lists, not two, i.e. you also need a list of pseudo-random choices to alternate between preserving either face or emotion from trial to trial: if you do this fully randomly, you'll get unbalanced, and exhaust one of the attributes before the other.

```
from numpy.random import shuffle

# make a list of 25 dictionaries of unique face/emotion pairs:
pairsList = []
for face in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
    for emotion in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
        pairsList.append({'faceNum': face, 'emotionNum': emotion})
shuffle(pairsList)

# a list of whether to alternate between preserving face or emotion across trials:
attributes = ['faceNum', 'emotionNum'] * 12 # length 24
shuffle(attributes) 

# need to create an initial selection before cycling though the 
# next 24 randomised but balanced choices:
pair = pairsList.pop()
currentFace = pair['faceNum']
currentEmotion = pair['emotionNum']
images = ['face_' + currentFace + '_emotion_' + currentEmotion + '.jpg']

for attribute in attributes:
    if attribute == 'faceNum':
        selection = currentFace
    else:
        selection = currentEmotion

    # find another pair with the same selected attribute:
    for pair in pairsList:

        if pair[attribute] == selection:
            # store the combination for this trial:
            currentFace = pair['faceNum']
            currentEmotion = pair['emotionNum']
            images.append('face_' + currentFace + '_emotion_' + currentEmotion + '.jpg')

            # remove this combination so it can't be used again
            pairsList.remove(pair)

images.reverse()
print(images)
```

Then just write the `images` list to a single column .csv file to use as a conditions file.

Remember to set the loop in Builder to be in a fixed order, not randomised, as the list itself has the randomisation built in.

Comment: Thank you Michael, that looks really helpful. I hadn't even thought of the pseudo-randomization; good call. I'll have a go and will let you know I I get on!

Comment: Hi Michael. This seems to work okay, but I am not sure. When I output my list via `print images`, it only outputs one image pair. This pair meets the criteria; i.e. _face_2_emotion_5, face_4_emotion_5_, so that's great! I have tried to write it to a csv file, but without luck. Is there a way to get the full list out of psychopy (1 column, 25 rows)?

Comment: My bad, but new error. I won't delete the above comment yet, but I think it might work once I solved the following issue: 1. I reckon I should use `random.shuffle(list)` rather than `shuffle(list)` (the latter doesn't work). 2. Somehow I forgot to copy the line `for choice in choices:`. So sloppy. I am troubleshooting this step by step in the shell, and the problem seems to be in the `faces.remove(face)` and `emotions.remove(emotion)` commands. The error I get is: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`. However, I am sure that we put it in the list.

Comment: PsychoPy Builder explicitly imports shuffle() from numpy.random, so it is available directly by name in code components.

Comment: This is a problem with posting untested code! The original algorithm posted is still subject to unbalancing due to random choices. e.g. you could have a run of six consecutive constant faces, which would exhaust that face number from the list, leading to the ValueError. I'll amend the answer to include some brute force protection so that the algorithm just keeps repeating until a successful list is generated. This has the theoretical risk of creating an infinite loop, but in practice seems to reach a solution after a few hundred iterations.

Comment: Brilliant! This code does produce a list of 25 images. It does take a few attempts (200-1500), but that is no problem for me at all. However, the list still contains duplicates (full example output is too long to post in a comment). I'm figuring that I need an extra remove line. (something like `list.remove([face, emotion]`?) or a loop that checks whether the last output is already present in `images` -> `pass`. Am I on the right track here? (I really appreciate your help so far. You're not just solving my current issues, but that I'm also learning a great deal about Python from you).

Comment: D'oh! No, its not that simple. The code doesn't include any protection against selecting the same emotion/face pair multiple times. I completely missed incorporating that constraint, which is, of course, inherent to the question. The algorithm needs to be revised completely, as currently the lists of faces and emotions are independent, whereas we actually need to be sampling from *pairs* of them to ensure no duplication. I'll give it some thought and revise.

Comment: OK, the algorithm now completely re-worked and the answer amended. Actually it is much simpler now and works deterministically in one iteration, so no need now for handling errors and the brute force approach. You should now get 25 unique combinations, satisfying your alternation criterion. If this works for you, please mark the answer as accepted as a guide to future readers.